# Animated matplotlib plot in an infinite loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, python-asyncio

I need to draw several points on some object in animation. Moreover, points come to me from the queue once a second (infinitely).

I tried matplotlib, but calling plt.show() creates a new plot instead of redrawing.

```
async def get_trams(self,geodata):
    while True:
        plt.clf()
        data = await self.queue_recv.get()
        if data is None:
            continue
        data = json.loads(data)
        
        for geo in geodata:
            x,y = geo.xy
            plt.plot(x,y)
        x,y = self.get_xy_from_data(data)
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.show()
```

As I understand it, all ways to create animations in matplotlib imply pre-initialization. Is it really possible to do this interactively?

Comment: Please add a complete minimal reproducible code. People should be able to run your code to suggest any kind of changes. For example, we do not know what geodata refers to in your script, we do not have access to the class methods such as queue_recv, and get_xy_from_data